# Oracle SQL - Column shows nullable yes despite check constraint

Tags: oracle, activerecord, oracle11g

I'm working on migrating all the tables in my schema to be partitioned tables. Since I'm on 11g instead of 12.2 I have to use `DBMS_REDEFINITION`. I've automated this with some Ruby code that executes the redefinition procedures for each table in my schema.

My issue is that after migrating, all of my non-nullable columns show `NULLABLE` - YES. This isn't actually true however, as I can check the constraints and there are check constraints defined for each of the columns that used to be `NOT NULL`, still enforcing the `NOT NULL` status. It seems like `DBMS_REDEFINITION` successfully copied the constraints, but it didn't reflect the `NULLABLE` status.

Is there a way to tell Oracle to get this back in sync?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer elsewhere:

https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/55081/why-is-sqlplus-desc-table-not-showing-not-null-constraints-after-using-dbms-re

Oracle copies the constraints but never turns validate back on. You have to manually do that with:

`ALTER TABLE <table_name> ENABLE VALIDATE CONSTRAINT <constraint_name>;`